# How can I insert a value in a determined column with and statment?

Tags: sql, firebird

Please someone could fix that question for me? don't know how to ask =/

I have 2 main columns:

CONTEST(PK) and RESULT 
and other column named RESULTCHECK

I need to insert the value "1" in the column RESULTCHECK where the RESULT has some statement like.

for example

```
CONTEST   RESULT
1          1,2,3,4,5
2          2,3,4,5,6
```

I want something like
INSERT INTO RESULTCHECK VALUES 1 WHERE RESULT LIKE '%2,3%'

how can I do that?

and in the end I have the currently result:

```
CONTEST    RESULT      RESULTCHECK
1          1,2,3,4,5   1
2          2,3,4,5,6   1
3          5,6,7,8,9   NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should listen to [@teresko's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835120/how-can-i-insert-a-value-in-a-determined-column-with-and-statment/5835210#5835210) about modelling your data correctly (apart from the English bit) , but otherwise the answer is

```
update TABLENAME set RESULTCHECK = 1 where RESULT like "%2,3%"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because your DB structure is **WRONG**.

There is this thing , called [many-to-many relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) and [junction tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table).

Basically, what you need is a

```
CREATE TABLE ContestResults(
   contest_id INT NOT NULL,
   result_id INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ( contest_id , result_id ),
   FOREIGN KEY ( contest_id ) REFERENCES Contests( contest_is ) ,
   FOREIGN KEY ( result_id ) REFERENCES Results( result_is )
)
```

Where you keep data about the relationship between many contests and many possible results.

P.S. and, please, use english names for the things in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Firebird 2.5, I think you can also use [SIMILAR TO](http://www.firebirdsql.org/rlsnotesh/rlsnotes25.html#rnfb25-dml-regex) for regular expression

> A new SIMILAR TO predicate is
>   introduced to support regular
>   expressions. The predicate's function
>   is to verify whether a given
>   SQL-standard regular expression
>   matches a string argument. It is valid
>   in any context that accepts Boolean
>   expressions, such as WHERE clauses,
>   CHECK constraints and PSQL IF() tests